# Dependent collection duplicates when I save entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have following domain mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "terminal_admin_role")
public class AdminRole {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id", sequenceName = "user_id")
    private Long adminId;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public AdminRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public AdminRole() {
    }

    // get set

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof AdminRole)) {
            return false;
        }

        AdminRole adminRole = (AdminRole) o;

        if (!role.equals(adminRole.role)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return role.hashCode();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "terminal_admin")
public class TerminalAdmin {
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "admin_role", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "admin_id", nullable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", 
                nullable = false) })
    private Set<AdminRole> adminRoles;      
    //...
}
```

and following code to execute:
controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addNewAdmin")
public String adminUsers(@ModelAttribute @Valid TerminalAdmin terminalAdmin,
        BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model, Principal principal, HttpSession session) {
    ...
    terminalAdmin.setCreateDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    terminalAdminService.saveTerminalAdmin(terminalAdmin);
    ...
 }
```

service:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveTerminalAdmin(TerminalAdmin newAdmin) {
    String rawPassword = newAdmin.getPassword();
    newAdmin.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newAdmin.getPassword()));
    terminalAdminDao.save(newAdmin);
    emailService.sendAdminCreatedEmail(rawPassword, newAdmin.getEmail(), newAdmin.getAdminRoles());
    emailService.sendAdminRegisteredForAdminEmail(newAdmin);
}
```

dao:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void save(TerminalAdmin terminalAdmin) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(terminalAdmin);
}
```

After it I see that admin roles binded to user duplicated in AdminRole table in database.

What Do I wrong? I have wrote equals method.

### P.S.

before saving in debug  I see following values:

[image]

Comment: It looks confusing to me: your `AdminRole` mapped to table `terminal_admin_role`, while the table `admin_role` is actually the join table for `TerminalAdmin` vs `AdminRole` (which means for tables `terminal_admin` vs `terminal_admin_role`).  `AdminRole`'s ID col named `role_id` but is actually `user_id` for sequence name, that means Admin is not a user but a role is more like a user?  Can the design be cleaned up to be a sane one? :P

Comment: and what's the meaning of `After it I see that admin roles binded to user duplicated in AdminRole table in database.` ? you see duplicated `AdminRole` created in DB (in `terminal_admin_role` table)? or you see duplicated relationships in `admin_role` table?  (see how confusing your naming is? :P )

Comment: @Adrian Shum **you see duplicated AdminRole created in DB (in terminal_admin_role table)?** - yes

Comment: For the `TerminalAdmin` coming in to controller, are the `AdminRole`s containing proper ID? If not, that's just normal as Hibernate will treat every incoming AdminRole being a new one

Comment: @Adrian Shum But I provide equals method which doesn't use id

Comment: admin roles from controller doesn't contains id

Comment: Hibernate does not work like this.  `ID` field is the identity of a persisted entity.

Comment: @Adrian Shum do you suggest make request to database and add ids ?

Comment: I suggest you to get a book of Hibernate and learn the basics first, and also remodel your entities to make it less confusing.  It is just so dangerous for someone don't even know the importance of ID field to continue developing on Hibernate/JPA, and it is actually more dangerous with such kind of confusing entity design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your new `TerminalAdmin`, the `AdminRole` it is referring does not contain ID.  ID is the identity of entities.  It does not use `equals()` to identify the identity.  Without IDs, Hibernate simply treat it as a new `AdminRole` to be persisted to DB (as you have set corresponding cascade options in `TerminalAdmin`)

There are some choices you may take

1. Change the ID of your `AdminRole` to the `role` String, or/and
2. Lookup the correct `AdminRole` by `role` string, and set them in your new `TerminalAdmin` entity, or/and
3. Contains the `AdminRole` ID in the incoming request, etc...

Comment: On jsp I render it like this:  **<form:checkboxes items="${adminRoles}" path="adminRoles"/>**

Comment: I don't understand why does not it return id

Comment: Not familiar with Spring MVC + JSP, and it is a irrelevant question anyway.  Raise another question (make sure you make it concise this time) for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385938/spring-mvc-miss-id-of-dependent-collection-when-combine-object-from-jsp