# Spring mvc miss id of dependent collection when combine form object from jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-form, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have following controller to return view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/adminUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminUsers(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
        Set<TerminalAdmin> users = terminalAdminService.getAllAdmins();
        session.setAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("adminRoles", terminalAdminService.findAllAdminRoles());
        model.addAttribute("terminalAdmin", new TerminalAdmin());
        model.addAttribute("generatedPassword", PasswordUpdateStatus.generatePassword());
        return "admin/adminUsers";
    }

terminalAdminService.findAllAdminRoles()
```

returns collection with ids:

[image]

On jsp I render it like this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="terminalAdmin" action="/admin/addNewAdmin">
    ...
    <form:checkboxes items="${adminRoles}" path="adminRoles"/>
    ...
</form:form>
```

I have the follwing controller to accept this object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addNewAdmin")
    public String adminUsers(@ModelAttribute @Valid TerminalAdmin terminalAdmin...){
      ....
}
```

In debug I see that `terminalAdmin` comes with adminRoles without ids.

[image]

How to fix this?

P.S.

It is continue of [Dependent collection duplicates when I save entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384989/dependent-collection-duplicates-when-i-save-entity)

Comment: do you see the ids in the html of the jsp page? (in the drop down)?

Comment: wich API are you using for persistance ? JPA ?

Comment: @fabien t JPA unrelated with this question

Comment: @Si mo No I don't see. I tryes to change but anyway id field reads to another field

Answer (score 1):

i prefer to use [Converters](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/type-conversion-in-spring-2.html), because for me it's cleaner

you should have something like the following:

```
public class StringToAdminRoleConverter implements Converter<String, AdminRole> {

    @Autowired
    TerminalAdminService terminalAdminService;

    @Override
    public AdminRole convert(String role) {
        return terminalAdminService.findRoleByName(role);
    }
}
```